# How to properly store each participant in the participants table?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a registration.blade.php where the user needs to enter some data to register in a congress.

For example if a conference has 4 ticket types "ticketype1", "ticketype2", "ticketype3" and "ticketype4" and the user selects that he wants 1 ticket of the ticket type "ticketype1" and 2 tickets of ticket type "ticketype4" it will appear in the registration.blade.php:

- A section for the user insert his name, surname and email (that is automatically populated if the user is authenticated).
- then it appears 3 sections because the user selected 3 tickets, each section will ask for the name and surname of each participant. Each section is associated with a selected ticket type.

The code to show this fields in the registration.blade.php is like below:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="name"
               name="name" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" required class="form-control" name="surname" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->surname : old('surname')}}">
    </div>

<!-- other form fields -->

<!-- if the all_participants is 1 in the confernece table it should appear for each selected ticket a section for the user 
    that is doing the registration insert the name and surname of each paarticipant -->
    @if (!empty($all_participants))
        @if($all_participants == 1)
            @foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
              @foreach(range(1, $selectedType['quantity']) as $test)
                  <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$k}}</h6> <!-- $k shows the ticket type name -->
                  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                      <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                      <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                      <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                  </div>
              @endforeach
        @endif
    @endif
    <input type="submit" href="#" value="Next"/>
  </form>
```

After the user insert info for this fields and click "Next" the code goes to the storeUserInfo() method below using an ajax post request.

**Doubt:**

My doubt is about store the necessary information in database.

When the "Next" button is clicked in the registration form I want to in the storeUserInfo() method:

- Create an entry in "registration" table, and this is already working fine.
- But then Im not having success in the next part, that is, to loop through all entries and create an entry in participants table with registration_id, ticket_type_id, name and surname for each participant. Because is necessary to have in account the ticket type, because to store a participant is necessary to store the ticket type where that participant is being registered through the "ticket_type_id" column. For example in each section that corresponds to a selected ticket there is the name of that ticket type with "`<h6>Participant - 1 - {{$k}}</h6>`" ($k shows the ticket type name). So the user that is doing the registration should enter the name and surname of each participant taking into account in which ticket type he wants to register each participant. My doubt is how to get that information in the storeUserInfo method so is possible to create the necessary entries in the participants table.

Do you know how this can be properly achieved?

// storeUserInfo method

```
public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
        //dd($request->all());

        $user = Auth::user();

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'email' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_name.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_surname.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ]);

        if($validator->passes())
        {
            $registration = Registration::create([
                'congress_id' => $id,
                'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'success'
            ], 200);
        }
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors =  json_decode($errors);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $errors
        ], 422);
    }
```

The `dd($request->all())` shows for example:

```
  array:7 [
  "_token" => "4AdKbRyAna2il5IrOl..."
  "name" => "John"
  "surname" => "Keane"
  "email" => "@gmail.com"
  "participant_name" => array:2 [
    0 => "John"
    1 => "Jake"
    2 => "Wilson"
  ]
  "participant_surname" => array:2 [
    0 => "Keane"
    1 => "W"
    2 => "L"
  ]
]
```

The `selectedTypes` array comes from the `RegistrationController` `storeQuantities()` method that stores the selected quantities for each ticket type and returns the user to the `registration.blade.php` page:

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){

        $ttypeQuantities = $request->get('ttypes');

        $all_participants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

        foreach($ttypeQuantities as $ttypeName => $quantity){
            if($quantity) {
                $ttype = TicketType::where('name', $ttypeName)->firstOrFail();
                $price = $ttype->price;

                $selectedType[$ttype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
                $selectedType[$ttype->name]['price'] = $price;
                $selectedType[$ttype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
            }
        }
        Session::put('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
        Session::put('all_participants' , $all_participants);
        //dd($selectedTypes);
        return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do this in a Loop. Assuming you've got a Model for `Participant`, which is linked to a `Registration`, you can do the following:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
  $participant = Participant::create([
    'participant_name' => $request->participant_name[$i],
    'participant_surname' => $request->participant_surname[$i],
    'registration_id' => $registration->id
  ]);
}
```

As your input is 0-based-indexed, you can loop over one of the array inputs (`participant_name`) and use that index to pull in the value from the other array input (`participant_surname`).

Edit: To handle missing ticket_type_id, need to include it in data being sent to view AND data being sent to the server.

First, add the property to each `$selectedType` being returned from the server to the view:

```
$selectedType[$ttype->name]['id'] = $ttype->id;
```

Second, add a `hidden` input to your form within the `loop` for `$selectedTypes` with the value in `$selectedType['id']`

```
<input type="hidden" name="ticket_types[]" value="{{ $selectedType['id'] }}"/>
```

Lastly, on the backend, handle `ticket_type` the same as you did the other two array inputs:

```
...
'ticket_type_id' => $request->ticket_types[$i],
```

Comment: Thanks but like that it appears: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'ticket_type_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `participants` (`participant_name`, `participant_surname`, `registration_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (john, keane, 5, 2018-04-23 19:02:09, 2018-04-23 19:02:09))". The error should be because the code is not having into account the ticket_type_id.

Comment: Because to store a participant is necessary to store the ticket type where that participant is being registered through the "ticket_type_id" column.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I missed some columns on the `Participant::create()` function; you'll need to fill in the extras :)

Comment: Thanks but I have that doubt about how to get the ticket type id, for example " dd($selectedTypes);"  shows for example: "array:1 [▼
  "ticketype1" => array:3 [▼
    "quantity" => "2"
    "price" => 0
    "subtotal" => 0}
  ]
]". There is no id,  do you know how to get the ticket type id so that is possible to store it?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're sending `ticket_types` to the server; probably need an `<input type="hidden" name="ticket_type[]" value="..."/>` although I'm not sure what the value would be. Would `ticket_id` be `ticketype1`? Might be missing something where you define `$selectedTypes`

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with that. There is a RegistrationController that has the storeQuantities method that returns the $selectedTypes to the registration.blade.php.